# Making yogurt I put the yogurt in before heating the milk

Tags: yogurt

I've made yogurt before, but it's been awhile and I was distracted. I added the yogurt before heating the milk. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Add more yogurt **after** heating. It shouldn't mind the inoculant you killed by heating.

Answer (score 1):

Add more yogurt. When you heated the mix up, you killed the bacteria that was going to ferment your milk for you, so, they should be inert. Then, you just add another shot of bacteria to start the culture after your mix cooled down.

Comment: If you don't have more yogurt to add, having mixed all your yogurt in the first time, you might still get enough bacteria by mixing your new yogurt in the container the old was in, or using the same spoon you had used before - it's not ideal because the bacteria will be less, which means it will take longer and have more chance of other bacteria getting in, but you might get enough to start the culture if you can't get more starter in time.